# What causes Windows Live Mail to fail with hotmail?

Tags: email, windows-live-mail, hotmail, activesync

I've been having trouble getting Windows Live Mail to receive mails from my Hotmail accounts. I'm getting the following error when trying to send\receive:

> Unable to send or receive messages for the Hotmail (X) account.
>
> Server Error: 0x8007000E Server:
>   'https://m.hotmail.com/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync' Windows Live Mail
>   Error ID: 0x8007000E

The problem has gone away for short periods and then come back for days and weeks.
What causes this and how do I fix it?

Comment: That is an out of memory or system resources error, not sure how to solve it. Try restarting the PC

Comment: Restarting the computer has not shown to be very effective, as the problem reoccurs very fast.
So far I've found that closing wlmail through Task Manager is enough right then.